# minishop2 не удаляет ресурсы из базы данных

Tags: sql, modx, minishop2

Возникла проблема: при удалении ресурса через админку все происходит как обычно: попадает в корзину, после чего удаляется полностью и исчезает из админки. Но при этом несмотря на то, что из админки он удаляется - он остается в базе данных и продолжает выводиться на сайте. При этом из полей ресурса вычищается все, кроме id и name. Ума не приложу в чем проблема. В логе есть 2 ошибки, но вроде как они с этим не связаны, ибо выскакивают не в момент удаления

`` [2021-07-06 14:44:10] (ERROR @ /home/a/*sitename*/public_html/core/model/modx/modx.class.php : 1031) `0` is not a valid integer and may not be passed to makeUrl() ``
`` [2021-07-06 14:44:10] (ERROR in resource 1 @ /home/a/*sitename*/public_html/core/model/modx/modparser.class.php : 1374) Bad link tag `[[~0]]` encountered ``

Может кто помочь? в модикс не особо понимаю, до меня недавно сайт на него как раз переносили. Таблица называется modx_ms2_vendors

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что ресурс прикрепляется вручную к одному из полей в настройках minishop, и удалять его нужно 2 раза ресурс и поле в настройках